# How to redirect to directory on root but using https

Tags: .htaccess, ssl, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I recently added ssl and would like to redirect to https but to a subfolder.

How should I modify my redirect to be https instead of just http?

Here is what I currently have in .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} main\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /directory/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an additional redirect rule for `http -> https` before your rewrite rule:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} main\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} main\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /directory/$1 [L]
```